# Standing positions during Birkhat Kohanim

Tags: halacha, blessing, rambam, synagogue, birchas-kohanim

The Rambam writes ([משנה תורה, הלכות תפילה וברכת כהנים ט״ו](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Prayer_and_the_Priestly_Blessing.15.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)) that people standing behind the Kohanim during birkhat Kohanim do not receive the beracha (and see Sotah 38b ([here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sotah.38b.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))):

> עַם שֶׁהֵם אֲחוֹרֵי הַכֹּהֲנִים אֵינָם בִּכְלַל הַבְּרָכָה. וְהָעוֹמְדִים מִצִּדֵּיהֶן הֲרֵי הֵם בִּכְלַל הַבְּרָכָה:
>
> The people standing behind the priests are not included in the blessing. Those standing at their sides are included in the blessing.

Consider the following shul set up with people standing at positions 1-5, and the Kohanim (in the middle) are facing forwards (arrow):

[image]

Person at location **1** is in front of the Kohanim, so he is included in the beracha.

Person at location **5** is directly behind some Kohanim, so he is not included in the beracha (according to this Rambam, this Gemara, others, etc.).

Questions:

1. Person **2** is 'in front' but at the side, so he seems ok. Correct?
2. Person **3** is at the side, but 'behind' some of the Kohanim. Is that ok? Does being "behind" for invalidation mean he is "directly" behind (like person **5**)?
3. Person **4** is at the side of the Kohanim, but not directly behind the Kohanim. Is that ok?

Comment: Are your descriptions of 3 and 4 reversed?

Comment: @JoelK, no i think its correct, but perhaps i didn't explain it well enough. please lmk what you were thinking and i can edit accordingly.

Comment: In what way is person 3 more "behind" the kohanim than person 4 is?

Comment: Person 3 is at least to their side, albeit to the side of the last one. Do you need to be in front of all of them like person 2